# Optimalization of firebase query. Getting data by ids

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, ngrx

I'm new in Firebase. I would like to create an app *(using Angular and AngularFire library)*, which shows current price of some wares. I have list all available wares in Firebase Realtime Database in the following format:

```
"warehouse": {
   "wares": {
      "id1": {
         "id": "id1",
         "name": "name1",
         "price": "0.99"
      },
      "id2": {
         "id": "id2",
         "name": "name2",
         "price": "15.00"
      },
      ... //much more stuff
   }
}
```

I'm using `ngrx` with my app, so I think that I can load all wares to store **as an object not list** because normalizing state tree. I wanted load wares to store in this way:

```
this.db.object('warehouse/wares').valueChanges();
```

The problem is wares' price will be refresh every 5 minutes. The number og wares is huge (about 3000 items) so one response will be weight about 700kB. I know that I will exceed limit downloaded data in a short time, in this way.

I want limit the loading data to interesing for user, so every user will can choose wares. I will store this choices in following way:

```
"users": {
   "user1": {
      "id": "user1",
      "wares": {
          "id1": {
             "order": 1
          },
          "id27": {
             "order": 2
          },
          "id533": {
             "order": 3
          }
      },
      "waresIds": ["id1", "id27", "id533"]
   }
}
```

---

**And my question is:**

Is there a way to getting wares based on waresIds' current user? I mean, does it exist way to get **only** wares, whose ids are in argument array? F.e.

```
"wares": {
   "id1": {
      "id": "id1",
      "name": "name1",
      "price": "0.99"
   },
   "id27": {
      "id": "id27",
      "name": "name27",
      "price": "0.19"
   },
   "id533": {
      "id": "id533",
      "name": "name533",
      "price": "1.19"
   }
}
```

for query like:

```
this.db.object('warehouse/wares').contains(["id1", "id27", "id533"]).valueChanges();
```

I saw query limits in Angular Fire like equalTo and etc. but every is for list. I'm totally confused. Is there anyone who can help me? Maybe I'm making mistakes in the design of the app structure. If so, I am asking for clarification.

Comment: remember to define the indexOn for performance benefits https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: which is the version of angularfire?

Comment: @Hareesh "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are saving the ids inside user try this way.

```
wares: Observable<any[]>; 

//inside ngOnInit or function
this.wares = this.db.list('users/currentUserId/wares').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => {
      const id = c.payload.key; //gets ids under users/wares/ids..
      let wares=[];
      //now get the wares
      this.db.list('warehouse/wares', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges().subscribe(res=>{
        res.forEach(data=>{
            wares.push(data);
        })
      });
    return wares;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a difference for firebase if I use `this.db.object('wallet/currencies/${id}')` instead of `this.db.list('warehouse/wares', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id))` ?

Comment: yes the `.list` return array of objects even if you got a single result. you need to loop through it to get the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do. I don't believe Firebase allows you to query for multiple equals values at once. You can however loop over the array of "ids" and query for each one directly.

I am assuming you already queried for `"waresIds"` and you've stored those ID's in an array named idArray:

```
for id in idArray {
    database.ref('warehouse/wares').orderByChild('id').equalTo(id).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }) 
}
```

In order to use the above query efficiently you'll have to [index your data on id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Your second option would be to [use](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlpIuU0fDYAhUS7VMKHTsgCewQygQILjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdatabase%2Fadmin%2Fretrieve-data%23child-changed&usg=AOvVaw3srxM-1VFz8Ku8Yi61abEq) `.childChanged` to get only the updated data after your initial fetch. This should cut down drastically on the amount of data you need to download.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can get exactly data that you want in firebase,

[See official Firebase documents about filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

You need to get each `waresID`

```
        var waresID = // logic to get waresID 
        var userId  = // logic to get userId
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("wares/" + userId).child(waresID);
        ref.once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot) {
               console.log(snapshot.val());
            });
```

this will return only data related to that `waresID` or `userId`

*Note: this is javascript code, i hope this will work for you.*